# relationship of polar unit vectors to rectangular

Tags: trigonometry

I'm looking at page 16 of Fleisch's *Student's Guide to Vectors and Tensors*.  The author is talking about the relationship between the unit vector in 2D rectangular vs polar coordinate systems.  They give these equations:

\begin{align}\hat{r} &= \cos(\theta)\hat{i} + \sin(\theta)\hat{j}\\
\hat{\theta} &= -\sin(\theta)\hat{i} + \cos(\theta)\hat{j}\end{align}

I'm just not getting it.  I understand how, in rectangular coordinates, $x = r \cos(\theta)$, but the unit vectors are just not computing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbols on the left side of those equations don't make any sense.  If you wanted to change to a new pair of coordinates $(\hat{u}, \hat{v})$ by rotating through an angle $\theta$, then you would have
$$
\left\{\begin{align}
\hat{u} &= (\cos \theta) \hat{\imath} + (\sin \theta)\hat{\jmath} \\
\hat{v} &= (-\sin \theta) \hat{\imath} + (\cos \theta)\hat{\jmath}.
\end{align}\right.
$$

Comment: The symbols in OP do make sense.

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on.  You are correct, @BradyTrainor.  The OP is looking at an orthonormal frame at point $(r, \theta)$ in polar coordinates.  This ends up being the standard frame $(\hat{\imath}, \hat{\jmath})$, rotated through angle $\theta$.

Comment: OK, this is a good clue.  I'm getting the picture that if I move forward and learn about transformations between the coordinate systems (as Brady mentions above) I may be able to come back at that time and understand this.  So thank you guys.

Answer (score 6):

To understand the formula:

1) draw a Cartesian coordinates with a unit circle (centred at origin with a radius of 1).

2) draw a vector pointing towards 2-oclock (so we have $\theta = 30$, this is arbitrary but I prefer this 30 degree angle as I tend to confuse the sin and cos on a 45 degree angle) with a length of 1, so this vector ($\vec{V}$) ends on the unit circle.

3) The key point to remember is that we are converting the **unit vectors** of the Cartesian system ($\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$) to those of the polar system ($\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$). **Unit vector** by definition is length 1.

4) To get to the radial unit vector $\hat{r}$: move $1\times cos(\theta)$ units along the x direction ($cos(\theta) \hat{i}$), then move $1\times sin(\theta)$ units along the y direction ($sin(\theta) \hat{j}$). That is the 1st equation: $\hat{r} = cos(\theta) \hat{i} + sin(\theta) \hat{j}$. Note that this how vector additions work. Draw it out on your paper and you will figure it out immediately.

5) Now to get the tangential unit vector ($\hat{\theta}$): that is, by definition, right-angle to $\hat{r}$, with a length of 1. So you will know that all you need to do is switch the positions of $cos(\theta)$ and $sin(\theta)$ in your 1st equation, and add a minus sign to one of them (so the dot product of these 2 resultant vectors is 0, equivalent to perpendicular). As we define anti-clock wise as the positive direction, the minus sign goes to the $\hat{i}$ direction. So here it is the 2nd equation: $\hat{\theta} = -sin(\theta) \hat{i} + cos(\theta） \hat{j}$.

6) If you dislike the step (5) way. Draw that $\hat{\theta}$ out on your unit circle: starting from origin, pointing towards 11-oclock (right angle to $\hat{r}$) and ending on the unit circle (length=1). To get to that end point by moving only along x- and y- directions, first move $-1\times sin(\theta)$ units on x-, then $1\times cos(\theta)$ units on y-. You get the same formula.

To reverse the conversion: from polar to Cartesian, you could simply do some pure algebra on the 2 equations we just derived, or use geometry to "move to" the target point you wish to derive.

Answer (score 2):

I too got stuck there, and found the answer in a YouTube video at:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwQTTJdAJP8. 
The difficulty I had was confusing the geometry of polar coordinates, where x = rcos(theta) etc, with the vector situation, where the radius vector is **resolved into its components** in the x and y directions, so, applying the formulae for expressing a vector in terms of its components to the case of the polar unit radial vector, we get the equation quoted: r^=cos(θ)i^+sin(θ)j^. Attached is an image from the video that gives the geometry of this equation.

[image]

[An image from the final moment of the video.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR5Uf.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The (endpoint of the) vector $(\cos\theta,\,\sin\theta)$ is on the unit circle, exactly at angle $\theta$ (if angles are measured from the $x$-axis, towards the $y$-axis). So, in polar form, we can say $r=1$ and $\theta=\theta$.

The other one, $(-\sin\theta,\,\cos\theta)$ is its rotated version, by $+90^\circ$. So, this has $\hat r=1$ and $\hat\theta=\theta+90^\circ$.

Comment: this is not right. r-hat is not a scalar, OP has the correct formulas. As well for theta-hat.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the right way to understand this entire thing is through this way.

Note that we are using the notation $\hat{x},\hat{y}$ to denote vectors fields. For example, $\nabla f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\hat{x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\hat{y}$ describe a vector on every single points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with
$\nabla f(x_0,y_0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)\hat{x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\hat{y}$

For any given point $(x,y)=(r,\phi)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, we should have a it's own basis transformation formula, which is where the $\phi$ comes from in the equation. Note that $\hat{r}$ for the point $(x,y)$ is simply the unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ pointing to point, and the vector $\hat{\phi}$ for the point $(x,y)$ is the unit vector orthogonal to $\hat{r}$ for the point $(x,y)$.

Using vector addition, we are done.

In our case here, $\hat{x},\hat{y}$ happens to be the same for every point in $\mathbb{R}$, while $\hat{r},\hat{\phi}$ is not necessarily the same for every point in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Caution: do not confuse $\hat{r},\hat{\phi}$ with the differential geometry object basis of tangent planes $\frac{\partial}{\partial r},\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$. $\hat{\phi}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$ point in the same direction, but the former is unit vector while the latter is not.

Comment: You have posted identical answers to this question, and to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4551697/ .  Do not do this.  If an answer addresses two different questions, then only answer *one* of those questions, and flag the other as a duplicate.