# How to write basis vectors in Cartesian coordinates in terms of cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, cylindrical-coordinates

Given a Cartesian coordinate system with basis vectors (e<sub>x</sub>, e<sub>y</sub>, e<sub>z</sub>)

and a Cylindrical coordinate system with basis vectors (e<sub>r</sub>, e<sub>θ</sub>, e<sub>z</sub>)

Why and how does:

e<sub>x</sub> = e<sub>r</sub>Cos(θ) - e<sub>θ</sub>Sin(θ) ?

e<sub>y</sub> = e<sub>r</sub>Sin(θ) + e<sub>θ</sub>Cos(θ) ?

This is from a derivation of the del operator in cylindrical coordinates from my lecture notes.

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. Shouldn't e<sub>x</sub> = e<sub>r</sub>Cos(θ) and e<sub>y</sub> =  e<sub>r</sub>Sin(θ)?

What is it with the extra Sin and Cos?

A simple, detailed derivation/ explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: This seems related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947583/graphically-representing-vectors-with-polar-unit-vectors-without-converting-to-c

Comment: The differential of a function $f(u,v)$ is $f_u du + f_v dv$. Apply this to $x=r\cos(\theta)$ to get $dx = \cos(\theta) dr - \sin(\theta) d\theta$, and similarly for $y = r\sin\theta$.